# Pass value from Objective C to Javascript using NimbleKit

Tags: iphone, objective-c

can anyone give me an idea about how to pass parameter from objective c to javascript using 
NimbleKit??

Thanks
Rony

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Still struggle with the NimbleKit? :)

Try using the next code:

```
// I assume that you have a global JS variable called "parameter"...
[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"parameter=7;"];
```

Comment: Hello Michael,
Thanks very much...yes..still struggle but all technical prob is almost solved...actually i am new in this field...only 2 months on objective c...
bye the way thank u very much..
Thanks
Rony

Comment: So, does `stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString` work with NimbleKit?